# How can I add a check to see if a collection on Shopify is available / published?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

How can I correct "Liquid error: comparison of String with 0 failed" when a collection is not published/ available?

If I make the collection unavailable/ not published I have 
"Liquid error: comparison of String with 0 failed"
on the frontend.

Removing 
`{% if collections['catalogue'].products_count > 0 %}`

shows "coming soon"

This is the line in question I think but I need to check there are products.

I've also tried adding

`{% if collections['catalogue'] %}`

I need the Catalogues section to be completely hidden until it's avaialble

```
{% if collections['catalogue'].products_count > 0 %}
    <div class="contain collection collection--home" data-intro="fade-in-up">
        <header role="banner" class="collection__title">
            <h1 class="h3 font--condensed text--upper">Catalogues</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="collection-grid">
            {% for product in collections['catalogue'].products limit:1 %}

                {% include 'collection-item' %}

            {% else %}

                <p>{{ 'collections.general.no_matches' | t }}</p>

            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

sorry I'm a liquid and Shopify nooob :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the publishing date since that is `null` when is not published.

```
{% if collections['catalogue'].published_at != empty %}
  // your code
{%- endif -%}
```

Please have in mind that you are checking for products count in your code but you are asking for collection availability which are 2 different things. A collection can be unavailable and still have products.

If you want to check for products swap it for:

```
{% if collections['catalogue'].products.size > 0 %}
  // your code
{%- endif -%}
```